# Equation to determine arc radius given a chord intersecting both ends of the arc, and x number of equal chords inscribing the arc (see image)

Tags: geometry

I've been scouring the internet to find a solution to this problem, but I can't seem to find anything quite right. I've tried finding the arc length between each smaller chord, but I end up needing the radius or central angle to do that. Every way I've turned I end up back here.

I'm looking for an equation to find the radius of an arc when I'm given the length of the chord (B) connecting its ends (subtending?), and *n* number of equal chords (A) inscribing the arc. These equal chords will be of a known length, connected at each end (chained, so to speak), and the "bookend" chords will intersect the ends of the arc [(three examples)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3vyQ.png).

The lengths of the chords in the examples are arbitrary, as is the number of inscribed chords.

I'm a n00b here, so let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

The chord length subtending an angle $\theta$ is given by

$ c = 2 R \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2} $

From the statement of the problem, the value of $c$ is given.  Also, for the $n$ smaller chords we have

$ d = 2 R \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2 n} $

Again, $d$ is give, so is $n$.

Dividing the two expressions, eliminates $R$, and we an equation in $\theta$ only.  The equation is

$ \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{ \sin \bigg( \dfrac{\theta}{2} \bigg) }{ \sin \bigg( \dfrac{ \theta}{2n} \bigg) } $

Cross multiplying, gives

$ f(\theta) = c \sin \bigg( \dfrac{ \theta}{2n} \bigg) - d \sin \bigg( \dfrac{\theta}{2} \bigg) = 0 $

The above is the function we want to find the root of.  This can be efficiently done using the widely-known Newton's method, where you make an initial guess $\theta_0$, and then you successively generate better approximations to the solution value of $\theta$ as follows

$ \theta_{k+1} = \theta_{k} - \dfrac{ f(\theta_k) }{ f'(\theta_k) } $

where $f'(\theta_k) $ is the value of the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $\theta_k$.

In a few iterations ($4$ or $5$), the method converges to the solution.

Once you have $\theta$ you can solve for the arc radius $R$ from the first equation, as follows

$ R = \dfrac{ c }{ 2 \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2} } $

As an explicit example, suppose you are given that the big chord of the arc is of length $ c = 30 $ , and $ n = 4 $ and each of the small chords of length $ d = 10 $ , then

$ f(\theta) = 30 \sin \bigg(\dfrac{\theta}{8} \bigg) - 10 \sin \bigg( \dfrac{\theta}{2} \bigg)  $

Its derivative is

$ f'(\theta) = \dfrac{30}{8} \cos \bigg( \dfrac{\theta}{8} \bigg) - 5 \cos \bigg( \dfrac{\theta}{2} \bigg)  $

We can start with a reasonable guess of $\theta$, for example $\theta_0 = \pi $

I've written a small code to implement the above, and the Newton iteration converged to a solution in $4$ iterations, the solution found was

$ \theta = 2.6251 = 150.4066^\circ $

Radius of the arc, using the above formula, evaluates to

$ R = 15.5144$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @Glorious Erin's answer, let $k n=\frac c d$ and $x=\frac \theta 2$ to face the equation
$$\sin (x) \csc \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)= kn$$
For a simple approximation, using my favored $\large 1,400^+$ years old approximation of the sine function
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0\leq x\leq\pi$$ you could have an *approximate* solution solving for $x$
$$\frac{(\pi -x) \left(5 \pi ^2 n^2-4 \pi  n x+4 x^2\right)}{\left(4
   x^2-4 \pi  x+5 \pi ^2\right) (\pi  n-x)}= kn$$ which is a cubic equation in $x$.
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$ where
$$a=4 (k n-1) \qquad\qquad  b=-4 \pi  (n+1) (k n-1)$$
$$c=\pi ^2 n (k (4 n+5)-5 n-4)\qquad \qquad d=-5 \pi ^3 (k-1) n^2$$
$$ 0 < k < 1$$

The discriminant being always positive, three real roots easily obtained using the [trigonometric solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions) with
$$p=\frac{\pi ^2}{12 (k n-1)} \Big[-4 \pi ^2 kn^3+\pi ^2 (4 k-11) n^2+\pi ^2 (11 k-4) n+4   \pi ^2\Big]$$
$$q=\frac{\pi ^3}{108 (k n-1)}\Big[-8 k n^4+(12 k-37) n^3+78(1-k) n^2+(37 k-12)n+8  \Big]$$ You will need to keep the last solution.

Using for example, $n=7$ and $k=0.3456$ this will give, as an *estimate*, $x=2.25974$ while the exact solution given by Newton method is $x=2.26435$ (that is to say a $0.20$% relative error).